# PFX keystore password vs password for export of certificate and key contained by the PFX-file

Tags: openssl, keystore, keytool, pfx, pkcs#12

I'm having a hard time trying to set a password on the PFX itself, not on the contained certificate. Let me try to explain

### Create the PFX file

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out internal-multidomain.pfx -inkey internalmultidomain.key -in internal-multidomain.cer -password pass:**********
```

### Verify the PFX file

Then I verify it using the following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in internal-multidomain.pfx -info
```

and it prompts me, not for "Keystore password", but for the "Import password". But since I use another pwd for the import than for the private key, I do assume that I can understand it as "Keystore password" - BUT:

### Very using keytool

Using keytool, when applying the password I used when using OpenSSL and the password argument fails, there is no password, I have to use blank ref.

```
keytool -list -keystore internal-multidomain.pfx
Enter keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

1, Oct 15, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

Trying to use keytool and setpasswd to set/change the password fails, because since I'm forced to use a blank password, it fails like this

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore internal-multidomain.pfx
Enter keystore password:
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
```

And using the pwd I applied using openssl also fails, and even the private key fails. So...I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the above commands are just fine, but it turned out that the issue was caused by different versions of OpenSSL / Keytool hosted on different servers.